# UDP Socket programming in C++ in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I am completely new to socket programming and beginner-intermediate in c++.
I have written a code in c++ and also another application in java. The java program will get data from the c++ code which generates data in seconds. I am trying to use socket programming to transfer data between these two. I have found some code here: [Socket programming tutorial](http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/07/socket-programming-tutorial.html). I am using the UDP java client from it. However, for the UDP server it only has the C code. I need to embed this code into my C++ app. therefore I need a c++ version of it. Can anyone help me with this? or give me a link that gives a tutorial on it. anyhow the C code is:[udpserver.c](http://www.pythonprasanna.com/Papers%20and%20Articles/Sockets/udpserver.c)

Comment: You should be able to take that (almost) verbatim ... what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: @Chris: when compiling I get this error: udpserver.c: In function ‘int main()’:
udpserver.c:48:64: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘socklen_t*’
udpserver.c:48:64: error:   initializing argument 6 of ‘ssize_t recvfrom(int, void*, size_t, int, sockaddr*, socklen_t*)’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must declare addr_len as socklen_t, not int.

---

That is, the first few lines in main should read something like:

```
int sock;
int bytes_read; // <- note how this is now on its own line!
socklen_t addr_len; // <- and this too, with a different type.
char recv_data[1024];
```

... Leaving everything else as it were.

Comment: I am quite beginner... I did this, and I got this error:udpserver.c:19:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘char’
udpserver.c:41:9: error: ‘addr_len’ undeclared (first use in this function)
udpserver.c:41:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in